# Creating Excel workbook in VB.Net panel

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, excel-2013

I am having an issue with a VB.Net application that opens Excel within a panel on my form. I am somewhat of a beginner at .Net, so this issue may be simple, although I have done a lot of searching and not found a solution.

Everything works fine when I run my application on an XP/Excel 2010 machine. I run into the issue when I run it on a Win7/Excel 2013 machine. I am using the Microsoft Excel 15.0 object library, though, so I think that should be good for Excel 2013.

My form has two buttons. One of the buttons opens an existing spreadsheet, and the other creates a new spreadsheet and adds some formatting. When running the application on the Win7/Excel2013 machine, I run in to issues creating a new spreadsheet (Incidentally, loading an existing spreadsheet works fine with no issues). The code will open a new spreadsheet, embed it in the panel, and complete the formatting. When this is done though, I cannot change cells in my spreadsheet. It is almost as if it is completely locked down.

When stepping through the code, I can tell that this behavior starts when the line of code sets the value of oSheet. Here is my code, after cutting out a lot of stuff not applicable to this problem.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core

Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim WithEvents oSheet As Excel.Worksheet


Private Sub btnNewConfig_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewConfig.Click

    'This routine will create a new configuration file.
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    oExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    oExcel.Application.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    oExcel.Visible = True

    'Maximize the Excel window within the panel
    SetParent(oExcel.Hwnd, pnlExcel.Handle)
    SendMessage(oExcel.Hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)

    boolFormatExcel = True

    oWB = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
    oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Address"
    oSheet.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 14

    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Description"
    oSheet.Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 35

    ........
```

The thing that is strange to me is that when I open an existing spreadsheet, it still sets oWB and oSheet in the same way, without any issues. This is how I did it when loading an existing configuration, and this works properly...

```
Private Sub btnLoadConfig_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadConfig.Click

    'This routine will prompt for a configuration file and load it into the form.
    'sExcelFileName = oExcel.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx")

    dlgOpenFile.Title = "Open a Configuration File"
    dlgOpenFile.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xlsx"
    dlgOpenFile.FileName = ""
    Dim DidWork As Integer = dlgOpenFile.ShowDialog()

    sExcelFileName = dlgOpenFile.FileName

    If DidWork <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sExcelFileName)
        oWB = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook
        oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Check if a valid configuration file is selected.  If so, load it.  If not, pop up a message to user.
        If oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Address" Then
            oExcel.Application.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
            oExcel.Visible = True

            'Maximize the Excel window
            SetParent(oExcel.Hwnd, pnlExcel.Handle)
            SendMessage(oExcel.Hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
```

..............

So, it seems to me like I am doing something that Excel 2013 does not like but I cannot seem to figure out what it is.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across problems embedding excel 2013/2016 in a custom control/panel/form etc I had a problem where, only when embedded, did the spreadsheet fail to keep focus and so prevented editing/typing.

In my instance the fix was to remove my line

```
xlsApp.WindowState=XlWindowState.xlMaximized
```

This is Where I was maximizing it inside the panel/user control - (I just use MOVEWINDOW on resize now)

The simple example in the link below worked and so pointed to a problem in my code.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/85d0972f-9655-48fc-ac5d-0ac7f9acc8b7/problem-with-setparent-api-in-excel-2013?forum=winforms

Basically I just kept commenting out my bits of code until it worked.

Hope this helps someone.

EDIT

Turning off the ribbon whilst its embedded brings the problem back (turning it off before embedding works ok) - so there are other things that will still cause this so better to test it fully.

My ribbon turn off code is

```
xlsApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this just after sheet declaration. It might work.

oSheet.UNPROTECT

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  The sheet is not actually protected, it just will not respond to mouse clicks.  Thanks for the reply...